# Парсинг JSON-строки

Tags: android, java, json

Пытаюсь разобраться как распарсить вот такого вида строку:

```
    {
"favorite": [{
    "Rutracker": "http://rutracker.org",
    "Pikabu" : "http://pikabu.ru",
    "SurfingBird" : "http://surfingbird.com"
}],
"bookmark": [{
    "title1" : "Сегодня я сделал то-то…",
    "some text": "а сегодня я сделаю то –то…"
}]
}
```

Как видно, у меня не статические имена в строке, поэтому мне нужно как то парсить по первому имени - `favorite` или `bookmark`. Как можно просмотреть внутренние поля в строке? Они динамически меняются. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: (facepalm)

Comment: Для того, чтобы распарсить json, нужно воспользоваться (барабанная дробь) парсером json. Ваш Кэп.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Возьми [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) и не парься - у прогера есть и более важные задачи чем парсить JSON строчку.